# Simple javascript in_array recursive function

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

So for PHP I have a handy set of function for doing an in_array on multi dim arrays:

```
function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
    foreach ($haystack as $item) {
        if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

However I have tried to recreate one similar in javascript but I cannot seem to get it to work.. this is what i have:

```
function in_array_r(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if(haystack[i] == needle){
            return true;
        }
        if(typeof haystack[i]=='object'){
            if(in_array_r(needle, haystack[i])){
                return true;
            }
        } 
    }   
    return false;
}
```

Can anybody spot why it isn't working as I cannot see why it doesn't..

Thanks,
John

Comment: What result are you getting? Error messages? Sample data to try, along with expected results would also be useful.

Comment: Have you some test cases?

Comment: Ah ha.. when the key is not numeric is fails..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works.. numeric and non-numeric keys.. doh!

```
function in_array_r(needle, haystack) {
    var length = haystack.length;
    for(var key in haystack) {
        if(haystack[key] == needle){
            return true;
        }
        if(typeof haystack[key]=='object'){
            if(in_array_r(needle, haystack[key])){
                return true;
            }
        } 
    }
    return false;
}
```